# Adding random noise to a group level variable

Tags: r, random, noise, jitter, multilevel-analysis

I'm performing multilevel analysis and, to check for statistical artifacts, I want to create new group level variables adding random noise to some group level variables (like school-level socioeconomic composition).

In `R`, the `jitter()` function allows to add random noise to a column easily:

```
jittered_variable <- jitter(variable)
```

However, this function add different values to a group level variable within groups.

Is there any way in `R` to add the same random noise to a group level variable within groups? For example, +0.5 for all the members of group 1, -0.3 for all the members of group 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.
Create a named vector with as many random values as there are groups. The names are the values that define the groups. Then add the random values `match`ing the data with those names.

```r
df1 <- iris[4:5]

set.seed(2023)
ngroups <- length(unique(df1$Species))
noise <- jitter(rep(0, ngroups))
noise <- setNames(noise, unique(df1$Species))
noise
#>       setosa   versicolor    virginica 
#> -0.001335442 -0.006592362 -0.013487298

df1$newcol <- df1$Petal.Width + noise[match(df1$Species, names(noise))]

# these differences are the random noise values
df1$newcol - df1$Petal.Width
#>   [1] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>   [6] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [11] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [16] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [21] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [26] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [31] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [36] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [41] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [46] -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442 -0.001335442
#>  [51] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [56] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [61] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [66] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [71] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [76] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [81] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [86] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [91] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#>  [96] -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362 -0.006592362
#> [101] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [106] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [111] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [116] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [121] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [126] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [131] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [136] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [141] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
#> [146] -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298 -0.013487298
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume a `runif` jittering, though this method can work with other functions/parameters as well (with modification).

Create a frame with the grouping variable(s) and the parameters for jittering, such as

```r
jitters <- data.frame(
  cyl = c(4L, 6L, 8L),
  neg = c(0, -0.3, -0.1),
  pos = c(0.5, 0, 0.1)
)
jitters
#   cyl  neg pos
# 1   4  0.0 0.5
# 2   6 -0.3 0.0
# 3   8 -0.1 0.1
```

From here, we can `runif` across all variables at once with a simple:

```r
set.seed(42)
out <- merge(mtcars, jitters, by = "cyl", all.x = TRUE) |>
  transform(mpg2 = mpg + runif(nrow(mtcars), neg, pos))
out
#    cyl  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  neg pos     mpg2
# 1    4 22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  0.0 0.5 23.25740
# 2    4 22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  0.0 0.5 23.26854
# 3    4 24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  0.0 0.5 24.54307
# 4    4 21.5 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1  0.0 0.5 21.91522
# 5    4 30.4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2  0.0 0.5 30.72087
# 6    4 33.9  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1  0.0 0.5 34.15955
# 7    4 26.0 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2  0.0 0.5 26.36829
# 8    4 30.4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2  0.0 0.5 30.46733
# 9    4 32.4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1  0.0 0.5 32.72850
# 10   4 21.4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2  0.0 0.5 21.75253
# 11   4 27.3  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1  0.0 0.5 27.52887
# 12   6 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 -0.3 0.0 20.91573
# 13   6 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 -0.3 0.0 20.98040
# 14   6 17.8 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 -0.3 0.0 17.57663
# 15   6 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 -0.3 0.0 21.23869
# 16   6 18.1 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 -0.3 0.0 18.08200
# 17   6 19.2 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 -0.3 0.0 19.19347
# 18   6 19.7 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 -0.3 0.0 19.43525
# 19   8 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 -0.1 0.1 18.69500
# 20   8 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 -0.1 0.1 17.31207
# 21   8 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 -0.1 0.1 14.38081
# 22   8 14.7 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 -0.1 0.1 14.62774
# 23   8 10.4 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 -0.1 0.1 10.49778
# 24   8 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 -0.1 0.1 16.48933
# 25   8 19.2 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 -0.1 0.1 19.11649
# 26   8 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 -0.1 0.1 15.20284
# 27   8 15.2 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 -0.1 0.1 15.17804
# 28   8 10.4 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 -0.1 0.1 10.48115
# 29   8 15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 -0.1 0.1 15.78939
# 30   8 15.5 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 -0.1 0.1 15.56720
# 31   8 15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 -0.1 0.1 15.04752
# 32   8 13.3 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 -0.1 0.1 13.36221
```

If you need a different function and *that* function doesn't vectorize the parameters like this, you may need to `Vectorize(func)(nrow(mtcars), neg, pos)` or similar, though that will slow things down (with large data).

We can "verify" (within reason) the jittering with:

```r
aggregate(cbind(mpg, mpg2) ~ cyl, data = out,
          FUN = function(z) c(min = min(z), max = max(z)))
#   cyl mpg.min mpg.max mpg2.min mpg2.max
# 1   4    21.4    33.9 21.61789 34.00383
# 2   6    17.8    21.4 17.78727 21.36633
# 3   8    10.4    19.2 10.30779 19.23546
```

where with `cyl == 4`, due to the range of `-0, +0.5` we expect `mpg.min <= mpg2.min`; with `cyl == 6` and a range of `-0.3, +0` we expect `mpg.max >= mpg2.max`; etc.